# Wireshark is not capturing OpenFlow packets from Mininet

Tags: wireshark, mininet, openflow

Hi everyone I downloaded the ISO file for investigating SDN features from here: http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/sdn-tutorial-vm/.

1) I run Mininet

```
sudo mn
```

to make basic topology

2) Then I run wireshark

```
sudo wireshark &
```

3) I tick all interfaces and start capturing
4) In mininet I do

```
h1 ping h2
```

5) I apply filter in wireshark "openflow", "of",....
6) But no OpenFlow packet are displayed

Could you help me please what is wrong? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, **openflow_v4** filter worked.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know where the controller is running. Is it a remote controller running in your host OS, or a controller running in the Mininet VM? Because you've run the basic topology, I'm going to answer based on the assumption that you're running the simulation over the basic ovs-controller that's enabled by default which runs within the VM.

Looks like you've run Wireshark from your host OS and not on Mininet. You made sure that you're listening on all the interfaces, good. But if the controller was running in the Mininet VM, these interfaces would have nothing to do with the OF packets and hence would not capture them. To actually capture the OF packets if the controller is in the Mininet VM, you've got to run an instance from the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting only the loopback interface: lo